# What are the words for when I mean something that is 'standard and also affordable'?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I am finding the right word for a commodity that got potentiality, good functionality/technicality and also is in affordable price in relation to other similar product.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use "affordable"

> This stove is an affordable alternative to the fancy high end competitors
> on the market.

The fact that it is good enough functionally is implicit in the way the comparison is framed with the word "alternative".

Just

> This is an affordable stove.

also implies that it's functional, but does not stress that fact.

Comment: *Affordable* generally implies that something is functional, dependable and reasonably priced.  *Cheap*, on the other hand,  implies that the object is flimsy, probably lacks durability, and the price reflects the lower quality.

Answer (score 1):

Sensible (of an object) practical and functional rather than decorative.
"Mom always made me have sensible shoes"

Comment: "Sensible shoes" doesn't sound like a common idiom. You can buy shoes sensibly, but that won't make the shoes sensible.

Comment: @Joachim:  Sensible shoes is a very common idiom.  It is used all the time and has been for decadez.

Answer (score 0):

There is no special word to express this. To emphasize functionality, you can say **it works**:

> I like this one. It works and it's affordable.

To emphasize that it has required features, you can say:

> This model has all the functionality I need, and it's affordable.

Or, more informally:

> This model has all the bells and whistles I need, and it's affordable.